# Flutter build IPA is not working in Xcode and terminal

Tags: flutter, xcode, ipa

I am trying to build a IPA in Xcode 14.3.1 using Flutter 3.10.5, with command 'flutter build ipa'.
However, it turns out error as below:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _FWFWKWebViewHostApiGetCodec
Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Encountered error while archiving for device.

I had try flutter clean, flutter pub get, pod update, pod deintegrate, pod install, but everything does not solve the problem.

Comment: Hey, please have a look at this issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/123903

Comment: Hi, @ColinLazarini. I had check with the issue but it does not solve my problem.

Comment: Can you add flutter doctor -v please ? Also share pubspec and config as in minimum iOS version deployment

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply, since the log and things are too long, can you check with this issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/129001